# Por qual motivo estão votando para fechar esta pergunta?

Tags: debate

[Qual Cipher Suite é compatível com Chrome 49 no Windows XP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215405/qual-cipher-suite-%C3%A9-compat%C3%ADvel-com-chrome-49-no-windows-xp)

Uma pergunta sobre Cipher Suites com uma excelente resposta, apenas gostaria de saber qual o motivo para votar para fechar, já que quem votou não fez nenhum comentário a respeito (não que fosse obrigado, mas no mínimo conveniente).

Não pode perguntas sobre Apache2? Não entendi o motivo.

Comment: É fora do escopo, porém tolerável. Eu dei o primeiro voto para fechar, mas percebi o equívoco. Não tinha percebido o contexto sobre Apache e mantive o foco no WindowsXP e Chrome, devido ao título. Seria bom colocar "Apache" no título, talvez. Desculpe o incômodo. Removi o meu voto.

Comment: Coloquei Apache2 no título. Eu fiz várias alterações para adaptar a pergunta aos padrões aceitáveis, acredito que minha primeira edição realmente não ficou clara.